# Pivot table with column totals

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pivot-table, summary

I've tried various samples I found through searches and I can't seem to get the result I require.

I have the following code

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT CR_RDate, PO_Num, RepName, CP_Amt, CS_ID, CS_Desc FROM  dbo.v_CommRP 
) as
PIVOT
(
  SUM(CP_Amt)
  FOR CS_Desc IN ([Cat1], Cat2], [Cat3])
 ) AS pv_CPR
ORDER BY CR_RDate, PO_Num, CS_ID
```

And it creates the following pivot table

```
CR_RDate    PO_Num  CR_Amt      RepName     CS_ID   Cat1    Cat2    Cat3
8/24/2015   166090  $100.00     Agent 1     2   NULL    $35.00  NULL
8/24/2015   166090  $100.00     Agent 2     3   NULL    NULL    $32.50 
8/24/2015   166090  $100.00     Agent 3     3   NULL    NULL    $32.50 
8/24/2015   2528968 $200.00     Agent 1     2   NULL    $70.00  NULL
8/24/2015   2528968 $200.00     Agent 2     3   NULL    NULL    $65.00 
8/24/2015   2528968 $200.00     Agent 3     3   NULL    NULL    $65.00 
8/31/2015   166090  $200.00     Agent 1     2   NULL    $70.00  NULL
8/31/2015   166090  $200.00     Agent 2     3   NULL    NULL    $65.00 
8/31/2015   166090  $200.00     Agent 3     3   NULL    NULL    $65.00
```

What I need is a total for Cat1, Cat2 and Cat3.  Ideally I'd be able to get a subtotal by CR_Date and PO_Num.

Then I need to put this into a table or something that could be presented on a website.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like below and let me know if this works. **I am assuming that columns Cat1,Cat2 and Cat3 are varchar.**

I used your query in CTE and removed the '$' from Cat columns. Then I took their sum, and concatenated the '$' symbol. This add/remove is working fine in Oracle 12c.

```
with pv as
( 
    SELECT * FROM
    (
     SELECT CR_RDate, PO_Num, RepName, CP_Amt, CS_ID, CS_Desc FROM  dbo.v_CommRP 
    ) as
    PIVOT
    (
      SUM(CP_Amt)
      FOR CS_Desc IN ([Cat1], Cat2], [Cat3])
     ) AS pv_CPR
    ORDER BY CR_RDate, PO_Num, CS_ID

)
select pv.*, '$'||cast(replace(coalesce(Cat1,'0'),'$','')+replace(coalesce(Cat2,'0'),'$','')+replace(coalesce(Cat3,''),'$','0') as varchar2(20))  as Total
 from pv
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: There's a couple of syntax differences but I got those worked out and used this code

Comment: Cool! If it works for you, please accept the answer by checking the tick on the left of the answer

Comment: Not quite.  It doesn't provide column totals, but row totals

Comment: If I do a summary query and do a union all, I almost get what I want.  Thanks for the pointer on this.